# PLS-00201: identifier 'T_CHAR' must be declared

Tags: function, oracle11g

This problem is driving me mad. This function compiles in One schema Successfully but When I try to recreate it in a different schema I get error:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'T_CHAR' must be declared
```

Here Is My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TMP_SPLIT(p_val VARCHAR2)
RETURN t_char IS
v_res t_char;
BEGIN
v_res := t_char(SUBSTR(p_val,1,1));
v_res.extend(LENGTH(p_val)-1);
FOR i IN 2..LENGTH(p_val) LOOP
    v_res(i) := SUBSTR(p_val,i,1);
END LOOP;
RETURN v_res;
END;
/
```

What is going on here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have created the `t_char` type in the second schema. That it not a built-in type, it's a user-defined type that has been created by you or someone else with access to the first schema.

If you aren't sure how the type was defined, you can run this from schema one:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TYPE', 'T_CHAR') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TYPE','T_CHAR')                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "SCHEMA_1"."T_CHAR" as table of varchar2(10);
```

... and then run that command in schema two, changing the schema name (or removing it):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "SCHEMA_2"."T_CHAR" as table of varchar2(10);
/
```

Obviously the actual definition of your type will be different, this is just a quick demo. From what the function is doing it looks like maybe it's a `table of char(1)`.

Comment: Thanks So Much. I did Not know